# Blackberry Tab bar control

Tags: blackberry

I want a tab bar in my application.I tried the sample code for it in blackberry but I want it at the bottom of the screen.I tried this code but it gives me uncaught runtime exception.Why this so? Whats the problem in this code?

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.image.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.toolbar.*;
import net.rim.device.api.util.*;
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import net.rim.device.api.command.*;

public class ToolbarDemo extends UiApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        ToolbarDemo theApp = new ToolbarDemo();       
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public ToolbarDemo()
    {        
        // Push a screen onto the UI stack for rendering.
        pushScreen(new ToolbarDemoScreen());
    }

    private final static class ToolbarDemoScreen extends MainScreen
    {
        public ToolbarDemoScreen()
        {              
            if (ToolbarManager.isToolbarSupported()) 
            {
                setTitle("Toolbar Demo");

                ToolbarManager manager = new ToolbarManager();
                setToolbar(manager);

                try 
                {
                    Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("myImg.jpg");
                    Image myImage = ImageFactory.createImage(myBitmap);

                    /*
                     * To create more buttons, Repeat the following lines 
                     * up until manager.add() 
                     */
                    ToolbarButtonField button1 = new ToolbarButtonField(myImage, new StringProvider("butn1"));
                    button1.setCommandContext(new Object()
                    {
                        public String toString()
                        {
                            return "Button1"; 
                        }          
                    });

                    button1.setCommand(new Command(new CommandHandler()
                    {         
                        public void execute(ReadOnlyCommandMetadata metadata, Object context)
                        {
                            Dialog.alert("Executing command for " + context.toString());
                        }           
                    }));

                    manager.add(new ToolbarSpacer(0));
                    manager.add(button1);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                Dialog.alert("The Toolbar is not supported on this device.");
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: I think Your requirement may be like this below link, Check it once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942225/tab-bar-in-blackberry-without-toolbarmanager/8967671#8967671

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
EncodedImage e1 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("home.png");
EncodedImage e2 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("map.png");
EncodedImage e3 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("members.png");
EncodedImage e4 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("message.png");
EncodedImage e5 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("settings.png");
EncodedImage e6 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("logout.png");


HorizontalFieldManager buttonPanel = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_TOP | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);

  VerticalFieldManager vfm=new VerticalFieldManager();
  vfm.add(new LabelField("Map"));
  vfm.add(new BitmapField(e2.getBitmap(),FOCUSABLE){
     protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){

        Dialog.alert("MAP");
        return true;
       }

  });
  buttonPanel.add(vfm);
  buttonPanel.add(new LabelField("  "));

  VerticalFieldManager vfm1=new VerticalFieldManager();
  vfm1.add(new LabelField("Members"));
  vfm1.add(new BitmapField(e3.getBitmap(),FOCUSABLE){
     protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){

        Dialog.alert("Members");
        return true;
       }

  });
  buttonPanel.add(vfm1);

  VerticalFieldManager vfm2=new VerticalFieldManager();
  vfm2.add(new LabelField("Message"));
  vfm2.add(new BitmapField(e4.getBitmap(),FOCUSABLE){
     protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){

        Dialog.alert("Message");
        return true;
       }

  });
  buttonPanel.add(vfm2);

  VerticalFieldManager vfm3=new VerticalFieldManager();
  vfm3.add(new LabelField("Settings"));
  vfm3.add(new BitmapField(e5.getBitmap(),FOCUSABLE){
     protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){

        Dialog.alert("Settings");
        return true;
       }

  });
  buttonPanel.add(vfm3);

  VerticalFieldManager vfm4=new VerticalFieldManager();
  vfm4.add(new LabelField("Logout"));
  vfm4.add(new BitmapField(e6.getBitmap(),FOCUSABLE){
     protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){

        Dialog.alert("Logout");
        return true;
       }

  });
  buttonPanel.add(vfm4);

  setStatus(buttonPanel);
```

Comment: thanks it works.But how to change its size.Because there should be separation between two components in tab bar.I hav only 3 elements in Tab bar

Comment: use vfm.setMargin for arranging the width.

Comment: sorry.I made a small change yesterday thats why its not working? Its working now.But It doesnt look like Tab bar. How to set background for that to look like tab bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the Exception, `Uncaught Exception: pushModalScreen called by a non-event thread` then you can try following code snippet for displaying an alert.

```java
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Dialog.alert("The Toolbar is not supported on this device.");
    }
});
```

And please check this question, [“pushModalScreen called by a non-event thread” thrown on event thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525210/pushmodalscreen-called-by-a-non-event-thread-thrown-on-event-thread).